# Any Python code for finding the difference between two timestamp variable

Tags: python, date, timestamp

```
final_started_date = [
'03/21/20 13:21:37','05/20/20 20:46:33',
'06/12/20 16:25:11','12/24/19 08:22:56',
'06/09/20 10:33:34','04/23/20 09:59:18',
'03/16/20 12:40:17','03/24/20 09:31:45',
'10/01/19 06:03:29','06/03/20 11:16:19'
]

final_ended_date = [
'01/29/20 05:26:44','11/06/19 07:14:00',
'05/03/19 13:30:51','04/02/19 10:51:45',
'06/25/19 15:17:08','08/14/19 13:01:50',
'03/31/20 09:15:34','04/08/20 11:09:07',
'04/04/20 11:39:30','05/28/20 14:07:02'
]
```

Here are exactly 10 dates on each list in Timestamp format. Now I need to find the difference in minute or in an hour between them. Help me by writing python code here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need a new list where the first element is difference between the first date in list 1 and the first date in list 2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the `datetime` library from Python.
First, we need to convert those lists into lists of DateTime objects.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

f = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"  # this format corresponds to how the data looks in your lists
final_started_date = [dt.strptime(date, f) for date in final_started_date]
final_ended_date = [dt.strptime(date, f) for date in final_ended_date]
```

Now we can use timedelta to calculate the difference in time between the two lists

```
dates_num = 10 
differences = [(final_ended_date[i] - final_started_date[i]).seconds for i in range(dates_num)]
```

Finally, the values in list are in seconds - if we want to get it as hour format:

```
from datetime import timedelta
differences = [str(timedelta(seconds=s)) for s in differences]
```

Output:

```
['16:05:07', '10:27:27', '21:05:40', '2:28:49', '4:43:34', '3:02:32', '20:35:17', '1:37:22', '5:36:01', '2:50:43']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this work. This was the simplest explanation and It worked in my case.

Comment: Hey @BikashPokharel, you're welcome. If that answer solved your question, consider marking it a solution or giving a point up :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define a method than can parse two date strings, and return the difference between them

You can then `zip` the strings to get a list of corresponding pairs from the initial two lists, and generate a new list of differences.

```
from datetime import datetime

final_started_date = ['03/21/20 13:21:37','05/20/20 20:46:33','06/12/20 16:25:11','12/24/19 08:22:56','06/09/20 10:33:34','04/23/20 09:59:18','03/16/20 12:40:17','03/24/20 09:31:45','10/01/19 06:03:29','06/03/20 11:16:19']
final_ended_date = ['01/29/20 05:26:44','11/06/19 07:14:00','05/03/19 13:30:51','04/02/19 10:51:45','06/25/19 15:17:08','08/14/19 13:01:50','03/31/20 09:15:34','04/08/20 11:09:07','04/04/20 11:39:30','05/28/20 14:07:02']

def time_between(dateString1, dateString2):
    date1 = datetime.strptime(dateString1, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
    date2 = datetime.strptime(dateString2, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
    return date2 - date1 # returns a timedelta

out = [time_between(x,y) for x,y in zip(final_started_date, final_ended_date)]

print(out)
```

This outputs a list of  [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)s, which you can then get info from.

```
[datetime.timedelta(days=-53, seconds=57907), datetime.timedelta(days=-197, seconds=37647), datetime.timedelta(days=-407, seconds=75940), datetime.timedelta(days=-266, seconds=8929), datetime.timedelta(days=-350, seconds=17014), datetime.timedelta(days=-253, seconds=10952), datetime.timedelta(days=14, seconds=74117), datetime.timedelta(days=15, seconds=5842), datetime.timedelta(days=186, seconds=20161), datetime.timedelta(days=-6, seconds=10243)]
```

---

[Working Repl](https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/63099371)

---